# Django 1.6 not loading css files

Tags: django-admin

Im using Django 1.6 version over apache webserver on windows.
Im not able to load the css file when accesisng the 
DJango admin panel ,once i login also im not able to load the css file

href="/static/admin/css/base.css"

```
PROJECT_ROOT = 'D:/DjangoProjects/firstproject/firstproject'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT,'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'                           
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # empty 
)
```

Am i missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

to add the admin files to static.

You should set a static url different than the static folder name - not required, but recommended

```
STATIC_URL = '/public/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT,'static')
```

Create an alias on the virtualhost (/etc/apache2/sites-avaliable/you_site.conf) for the STATIC_ROOT

```
Alias /public /var/www/public_html/your_project/static
<Directory /var/www/public_html/your_project/static>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Restart apache

Comment: are you seeing any errors on /var/log/apache2/error.log file?

Comment: sorry, I forgot you're in windows... check the apache error log and see if you have any permissions error...